# Resolve name without touching /hosts file in Python

Tags: python, dns

I am making a little game in python. One of the tasks has to do with accessing a fictitious web page that is in a local file.
Using `python -m http.server 80` and modifying the host file to `127.0.0.1 mysecretlogin.by` I can achieve the desired effect: that the name appears in the browser. My question is if any method to achieve this without modifying the `/hosts` file or is it impossible since the request happens on the DNS server and the only way to bypass it is by modifying that file.
Thank you

Comment: Is the domain given or can you choose it freely?

Comment: I choose it freely, is just for a game, for making it more realistic

Comment: do you control the browser?  If so, you could set the proxy to point to a really dumb local proxy that just returns the same web server pages regardless of the hostname

Comment: the point is making it all as a python game, not change it nothing but Python scripts

Comment: Checkout https://nip.io/ or https://xip.io/. They do dynamic dns resolution. Just use `"any.thing.127.0.0.1.xip.io"` and it will resolve to your localhost.

Comment: @schwobaseggl i this seems something that will work, now i have to figure how to work with it. Thanks